# Android - Unit testing with Robolectric is very slow

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric 4.2 to write unit test cases for one of my Android applications. The test case is very simple like below:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    landingActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LandingActivity.class);
}

@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull() {
    assertNotNull(landingActivity);
}
```

But its taking forever to get completed. Can someone help me out what is happening and is there anything I'm missing.

Comment: What kind of times are you seeing? Was it quicker with previous versions of robolectric? Roboletric is inherently slow but slower than usual test times are a known issue with version 4+ https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4587

Comment: Yes, it can take up to minutes I think. But the first test is usually much slower, than other tests in the class. So if you duplicate it, you should se the second test to be much more faster. I'm constantly getting 20s on one test, and 0.1xx on other tests in the class.